Solving linear systems in Finite fields

Consider the following matrix in image. How to find a set of 16 integers with no repetition in [0, 31] such that applying the matrix to this set written as a column vevtor gives the remaining 16 numbers in [0, 31]. The addition is binary.

What does "random" mean in this question? How do you apply a matrix to a set? Do you mean, treat the $16$ integers as a column vector, and multiply that vector by the matrix? The last row of the matrix has $12$ ones in it. You can't add up $12$ different integers in $[0,31]$ and get an integer in $[0,31]$. Youi get at least $66$. And where are the finite fields?

What Gerry said. Also, where did this matrix come from? It looks a bit like but not quite a codebook of some errorcorrecting code, or may be a CRC where some complementation is used to avoid the all zeros message passing the check or some such.

To clarify the addition is xor. The 16 integers do make a column vector for A to be applied to it.

"To clarify the addition is xor. The 16 integers do make a column vector for A to be applied to it." That information should be edited into the body of the question, not hidden down here in the comments, please.

@GerryMyerson thanks for this I have edited above.

Am I interpreting this correctly: find a vector $v \in \mathbb{F}2^{32}$ with $16$ non-zero entries such that $Mv + v = 0$, where $M \in M{32}(\mathbb{F}_{2})$ is the given matrix?

A vector should be in the field of $2^5$ elements.

Are you sure about the matrix? Here is a text version of that matrix, that could be copied into the question and edited if needed.
The last 4 columns are the same as the first 4 rows reversed.
1 1 1 1  1 1 1 0  0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0  
1 1 1 1  0 0 0 1  1 1 0 0  0 0 0 0  
1 1 0 0  1 1 0 1  1 0 1 0  0 0 0 0  
1 0 1 0  1 0 1 1  0 1 1 0  0 0 0 0  
0 1 1 0  0 1 1 1  0 0 1 0  0 0 0 0  
1 1 1 1  0 0 0 0  0 0 0 1  1 1 0 0  
1 1 0 0  1 1 0 0  0 0 0 1  1 0 1 0  
1 0 1 0  1 0 1 0  0 0 0 1  0 1 1 0  
1 0 0 1  0 1 0 0  0 0 0 1  1 1 1 0  
1 1 0 0  0 0 0 1  1 0 0 1  1 0 0 1  
1 0 1 0  0 0 0 1  0 1 0 1  0 1 0 1  
1 0 0 1  0 0 0 0  1 0 0 0  1 1 0 1  
1 0 0 0  1 0 0 1  0 0 1 1  0 0 1 1  
1 0 0 0  0 1 0 0  1 0 1 0  1 0 1 1  
1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0  0 1 1 0  0 1 1 1  
0 1 1 1  1 1 0 1  1 0 1 0  1 1 1 1  


This matrix is linearly dependent. The xor of the 11 selected rows shown below sum (xor) to zero:
1 1 1 1  1 1 1 0  0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1  0 0 0 1  1 1 0 0  0 0 0 0

1 0 1 0  1 0 1 1  0 1 1 0  0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0  0 1 1 1  0 0 1 0  0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1  0 0 0 0  0 0 0 1  1 1 0 0
1 1 0 0  1 1 0 0  0 0 0 1  1 0 1 0

1 0 0 1  0 1 0 0  0 0 0 1  1 1 1 0
1 1 0 0  0 0 0 1  1 0 0 1  1 0 0 1
1 0 1 0  0 0 0 1  0 1 0 1  0 1 0 1

1 0 0 0  1 0 0 1  0 0 1 1  0 0 1 1

1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0  0 1 1 0  0 1 1 1
-------  -------  -------  -------
0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0

Doing a brute force search the best I got was 31 unique values, no duplicates of the 16 values to multiply. For example, in this case there is one duplicate (hex 15) in the 16 resulting values:
00 01 02 03 04 05 07 08 0a 0c 10 13 14 16 18 1e input
06 0e 12 15 19 11 1f 1c 0f 1a 1d 15 09 0d 0b 17 output

This was done by choosing a combination of 16 of 32 values for the input, in sequential order, without any permutations. The number of permutations is 16! = 20,922,789,888,000.

Yes they linearly dependent but I need a required solution. At least a way towards finding such a solution

This is a question arised in my own work. I don't know what can I add more on this. This is a system of equations with 16 knowns (we can assume them to be any 16 between 0 and 31 and the equations should give the other 16 numbers.

@Mathslovershah - as the question is written, there are 32 unknowns, the 16  values to be multiplied and the 16 results.. That's comb(32,16) = 601,080,390 combinations and 16! = 20,922,789,888,000 permutations = 12,576,278,705,767,096,320,000 possible combinations and permutations. Also what does this have to do with finite field?

The field of 32 elements is a finite field and we dont need any multiplication for this matrix, we can use Guassian elimination and since the matrix is binary and the variables from the finite field of 32 elements the sum is also XOR.

There are many solutions but I need those solutions in which the variables are all 32 elements with no repetitions

@Mathslovershah - Gaussian elimination would require knowing the 16 result values and also a linear independent matrix. It isn't needed though, just choose 16 of the 32 values and multiply by the matrix. I updated my answer to show an example of trying combinations of 16 of 32 values, but didn't try permutations, since that is 16!. The best I got was 31 values, two duplicates in the 16 result values.

Yes I also searched through a bruteforce but could not find a list of all 32 values. Thanks for your input.
